# Retrieve distinct row from the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a table Masterproduct and I want to retrieve only a single row for every 'ProductDivisionID' along with the check whether the 'StatusID' of any row is 2 for a particular 'ProductDivisionID'

Comment: if you want product_id also in the selection then you use GROUP BY and aggregation function for the requirement it won't work by simply, if you post your output data then I can suggest properly.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you want a list of `productDivisionID` values for those division where any row has a `StatusID` of `2`.  In this case, you could use aggregation over divisions, and count the number of occurrences:

```
SELECT productDivisionID
FROM Masterproduct
GROUP BY productDivisionID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Or even simpler, just use a `WHERE` condition to remove records where the `StatusID` is not `2`, and then `SELECT DISTINCT` to get the list of divisions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT productDivisionID
FROM Masterproduct
WHERE StatusID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you columns productID as maximum value and StatusID as 2 for each productDivisionID

```
SELECT productDivisionID, MAX(productID) as productID , MAX(StatusID) As StatusID
FROM Masterproduct
WHERE StatusID = 2
GROUP BY productDivisionID
```